# How can I select this specific part of a string using regex?

Tags: python, regex

Hi and thank you for your time.

I have the following example string: "`Hola Luis,`" but the string template will always be `"Hola {{name}},`".

How would the regex be to match any name? You can assume the name will follow a blank space and "`Hola`" before that and it will have a comma right after it.

Thank you!

Comment: It would have been nice to show us what you tried before ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), assuming that as you mention, the format is *always the same*:

```
import re
s = "Hola Luis,"
re.search('Hola (\w+),', s).group(1)
# 'Luis'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s = 'Hola test'
re.match(r'Hola (\w+)', s).groups()[0]
```

results:

```
'test'
```

Comment: how it different from @yatu solution

Comment: i didnt saw it when writing.

Comment: @ you have to change `'Hola (\w+)'` to `'Hola (\w+),' as mention by OP, STRUCTURe there

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from @yatu,

**Without regex**:

```
print("Hola Luis,".split(" ")[1].strip(","))
```

**Explanation**:

```
split(" ") # to split the string with spaces 
[1]        # to get the forthcoming part
strip(",") # to strip off any ','
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Luis
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/) and your requirements, I'll use the following regex: [`(?<=Hola )[^,]+(?=,)`](https://regex101.com/r/tHvhFt/1).